# Playstation Plus Instant Game Collection on same device, from multiple countries

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus

TL;DR - Are "Instant Game Collection" games bound to your machine, or to your PSN account?

I currently own a PS3 with an expired PS Plus subscription on a (Canadian) Account, and I have a bunch of games on it from the Instant Game Collection (meaning, if I subscribe again, those games will be active).

If I purchase a PS Plus subscription on a different (United States) account, will I have access to those games?

Comment: Ive been under the impression that once your account expires you loose those games.... I also highly doubt that those downloads would be available in different countries, but it might be best to reach out to Sony on this.

Comment: @buschschwick Games are tied to your account, not your country. I live in the Netherlands and my PS3/PS4/Vita are all EU, but my PSN account is American and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Games are bound to the PSN account.